# tabular* right border misplaced

Tags: tables, tabularx, border

I know this may sound stupid of a question but I am a very beginner in LaTeX.

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|c|}
        \hline                                
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}           
        \textbf{\textbf{Description sommaire}}:        
    \end{tabular} 
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to force a table into page width. I used `{tabular*}` for that and it worked. But now I have an issue with borders. The left border is displayed normally however the right one is misplayed.

[image]

My table has only one column and I want the right border to be on the right end of the table. How can I do that?

Comment: If your tabular-like material contains a single column, you shouldn't be using a `tabular*` environment to achieve your typesetting objective. `tabular*` is designed to achieve the desired width (here: `\textwidth`) by dynamically enlarging the amount of intercolumn whitespace. For this setup to have any chance to work, there must be at least two columns. You really should be looking into using a `tabularx` environment.

Answer (score 2):

`tabular*` has a special syntax which must be followed to take advantage of its capability to expand the table to the whole textwidth. Here is the required syntax:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|c|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c|}
        \hline                                          
        \textbf{\textbf{Description sommaire}}: &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

> [image]

Otherwise, just use the more-common `tabularx` environment (which I recommend):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
        \hline                                          
        \textbf{\textbf{Description sommaire}}: &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

this gives the same result plus text-wrapping as a bonus.

Comment: I feel  that the OP is searching really for a single cell as header of plain text outside the float. If this is true a  float with `tpb` options will be very dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make a framed section-like title?

Because then, make a float (a `table`)  is the worse idea possible. This can displace the title to anywhere. Although with `[H]` option you make that the float does not float, still a `table` environment  is completely unnecessary. May be you are using it to avoid indentation of the table a add vertical spaces, but this can be solved better without a float (respectively, with `\noindent` and some vertical spacing command as `\bigskip`, or maybe set `\parindent` to 0pt and `\parskip` to some more).

Nested tabulars  do not make sense either. One (simple) tabular is enough, or a framed box (`\fbox{}`) that can take the line width less the space used by the framed box, as a  `\makebox`, a `\parbox`, or a minipage environement, may be in a section redefinition or alternatively, use a very configurable boxing package as `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`, or simply write some \vrules and \hrules around, without making any box.

The example show 5 of the many alternatives. Use the one that makes you happy.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Padding of \fbox{} 
\setlength\fboxsep{.5em}

% Some dummy text between solutions, just to see the layout 
\def\loreipsum{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    
elit. Fusce elit lectus, dapibus eget pellentesque eu, ultricies 
vel turpis. Cras quis convallis nibh.}

% for solution 2 only
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fsection{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
{1em}{1em}{\bfseries\framedbox}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\framedbox[1]{\noindent%
\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}

% for solution 5 only
\usepackage{mdframed}


\begin{document}

\loreipsum

% solution 1
\bigskip\hrule
\noindent
\vrule height 12pt depth 6pt width 0.4pt 
{ \bfseries Description sommaire}\hfill\vrule
\hrule\bigskip

\loreipsum

% solution 2
\fsection*{Description sommaire} 

\loreipsum

% solution 3
\bigskip
\noindent\fbox{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule][l]
{\textbf{Description sommaire}}}\bigskip

\loreipsum

% solution 4
\bigskip
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\setlength\tabcolsep{.5em}
\noindent\begin{tabular}%
{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}\hline
\textbf{Description sommaire} \\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\bigskip

\loreipsum

% solution 5
\begin{mdframed} 
\textbf{Description sommaire}: 
\end{mdframed}

\loreipsum

\end{document}
```